How to apply Server Side Rendering SSR in existing NodeJS and Angular project?
I have one NodeJs app which provide static dist files from one Angular 17 app. Now I need to implement SSR. I try to find way to do, but I can't find anything.
How can I implement this?
I looked for solutions on the internet, I read manuals, but everywhere they talk about creating and using Angular Universal, but this is killing my NodeJS application.

With the release of Angular 17 @angular/ssr was released. It's creating a nodejs enviornment thats serving the prerendered pages.
If you want more controll over the behavior you can check out https://analogjs.org/.
I need more information to understand what you want to achieve, in order to help more precisly.

I have app NodeJs + ExpressJs who serve bundled app of Angular17 (index.html and assets), and this NodeJs is reposible for API's, middlewares.
The both app, is a large app.
The both projects, is separated, even in GIT.

I think there might be some confussion messing around here.
Angular and its server side rendered content only serves as frontend.
If you want both to be accessable in one domain you should use a reverse proxy such as Nginx.
What is the reason node.js should serve the Angular application?

The reason is I want to be running only one application, in this case NodeJS+Expressjs. Who will serve static files generated by Angular Build and Api's. Isnt possible? =/

Not really, the server side part of Angular needs to run. You could start it via the nodejs backend. But I would recommend using a script or docker.

Now Im understanding. Please, can you show me one example using script? Starting it via the nodejs?

You need to be able to run the command npm run start. If you can't invoke this command on your server, look no further...
